# Suppose $x$ and $y$ are in the same orbit. Show that $G_x$ and $G_y$ are conjugate subgroups.

Tags: group-theory

Let $X$ be a $G$-set and $x,y \in X$. Let $G_x$, $G_y$ be the stabilizers of $x$ and $y$ respectively. Suppose $x$ and $y$ are in the same orbit. Show that $G_x$ and $G_y$ are conjugate subgroups.

If $x$ and $y$ are in the same orbit then $G_x=G_y$. How do I show that $G_x$ and $G_y$ are conjugate subgroups of $G$?

Comment: Write $y = g\cdot x$. Write down the definition of the stabiliser. Stare at it. Find enlightenment.

Comment: $x$ and $y$ being in the same orbit does not imply that $G_x = G_y$. In fact, you are trying to prove that $G_x$ is conjugate to $G_y$, which is not the same as them being equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $y\in \mathcal{O}_x$, we can find an element $g\in G$ such that $y = g\cdot x$. Now define the isomorphism
$$\phi:G_x\to G_y$$
by $\phi(a) = gag^{-1}$
and check that

- $\phi$ is well defined.
- $\phi$ is a homomorphism.
- $\phi$ is injective.
- $\phi$ is onto.

Thus, $G_x$ and $G_y$ are conjugate.

Comment: What does "well-defined" mean?

Comment: Take $a\in G_x$, is it true that $\phi(a)\in G_y$? Then we say $\phi$ is _well defined_.